# Annotations in web applications

Tags: struts2

I want to know why Annotations are preferred over XML in Struts2 Applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to refactor code with annotations than refactor code and then find out you broke your application because you forgot to change the XML file. This is more of a general answer than just for Struts 2, though.